# Hamcrest collection assertions merge several hasProperty in one

Tags: java, hamcrest

Actually I'm testing an item of a collection contains a property `key equalTo("key")` and has a property `value equalTo("value")`, in two sentences:

```
assertThat(categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos(), contains(hasProperty("key", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getKey()))));
assertThat(categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos(), contains(hasProperty("value", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getValue()))));
```

Is it possible to merge them in one?

Comment: Just a wild guess, you could try something like: `assertThat(categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos(), hasItems(hasProperty("key", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getKey()))), hasProperty("value", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getValue()))));` but I'm not sure what benefit this gives you over what is in your question. It's nice to keep your tests as simple and readable as possible.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Nevertheless, the compiler warns me: `Type safety: A generic array of Matcher<? super Object> is created for a varargs parameter`. Any idea?

Comment: Yes. So whatever class this returns: `categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos()` Change the code in your test to:
`assertThat(categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos(), hasItems(Matchers.<YourClass> hasProperty("key", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getKey()))), hasProperty("value", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getValue()))));` See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33123568/3899529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
assertThat(
    categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos(), hasItems(Matchers.<YourClass>
        hasProperty("key", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getKey())),
        hasProperty("value", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getValue()))
    )
);
```

Where  is whatever class type this method returns returns: `categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos()`

See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33123568/3899529

But I'm not sure what benefit this gives you over what is in your question. It's nice to keep your tests as simple and readable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that **the same item** (of your collection) fulfills **both conditions at the same time**, you'd better combine them in one single matcher with the **AllOf** matcher :

```
assertThat(categorizedFuaDto.getMetainfos(),
        hasItem(allOf(hasProperty("key", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getKey())), 
                        hasProperty("value", equalTo(receivedMetaInfoValue.getValue())))));
```